# not understanding the return statement in hashmap when converting a key to array

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

**`return map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);`**

Can anybody explain me the above `return` statement ? what it does and what's string constructor doing ?

For more info
**the program is here**

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConvertMapTester {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Map<String , String> map = new HashMap<>();
        fillData(map);

//      //Convert keys to array
//      String[] strings = keysAsArray(map);
//      for(String string : strings)
//      {
//          System.out.println(string);
//      }

        //Convert keys to list
        List<String> list = keysAsList(map);
        for(String string : list)
        {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }

    private static void fillData(Map<String , String> map)
    {
        map.put("android", "google");
        map.put("iphone", "apple");
        map.put("nokia", "microsoft");
    }

    private static List<String> keysAsList(Map<String, String> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        return list;
    }

//  private static String[] keysAsArray(Map<String, String> map) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);
//  }
}
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `HashMap<K,V>.keySet()` delivers all keys.

To convert this to a `K[]` there exists a method

```
K[] toArray(K[] obj);
```

It needs a paramter (`obj`) to determine the class K. Because at runtime, because of the actual value of K not saved by the comiler (type erasure), one has to determine the class from `obj`.

If `obj` has the correct size for the resulting array, `obj` is used, otherwise a new array is created and returned. Hence passing

```
new String[map.keySet().size()]
```

so this parameter may be used for the result. `new String[0]` would have the same effect, but create an additional array.

Answer (score 0):

> what it does and what does the string constructor does?

That is not constructor. It is **inline declaration** of a String array. That line is equivalent of

```
String[] strArray = new String[map.keySet().size()];
return map.keySet().toArray(strArray]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates an array of Strings and populates it with the keys of the map, and returns this array.

`map.keySet()` returns a Set of all the keys in the Map.
`toArray` converts it to an array.
`new String[map.keySet().size()]` creates an array of Strings of a size equal to the number of elements in the Set of keys, and this array is passed to the `toArray` method, which populates it with the keys of the map and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

It gets all keys of the map as an array.

This is done by getting the Set of keys with `map.keySet()` and calling the Sets [toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[])) method.

This method requires an array of the keys type to be supplied. In this case `new String[map.keySet().size()]`. As all keys fit into this array it will be used to store the data and then be returned(see documentation)

If the number of keys is unknown an anonymous empty array would have sufficed (`new String[]{}`)

Answer (score 0):

```
return map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);
```

means return a `map.keySet()` which is converted to array of Strings of `size map.keySet().size()`

i.e. return a String Array of `map.ketSet()` of size is equal the count of items in `map.keySet()`